# .htaccess как вместо изображения показать страницу

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть скрипт который генерирует и вывод на экран изображения.
Как при помощи .htaccess сделать так чтобы когда набрал в адресной строке адрес http://site.ru/image.png выводился на экран файл image.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^avatar.png$ avatar.php [L]
```